# Download multiple Restful resources as zip

Tags: javascript, rest

After reading around for a couple of hours I'm not sure the best way to approach it. I've got a list of restful resource urls (same domain) selected by the user, and I'd like to package those for immediate download. Any pointers to a 'correct' method would be great :)

I'm using Django Rest Framework and have tried using [JSZip.js](http://stuk.github.io/jszip/) on the front end, but just get garbage - the zip file wont open (I assume I'm doing something wrong with the type somewhere...)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/test/?format=fits",
        contentType: "application/fits",
        accepts: "application/fits",
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log("Success");
         var zip = new JSZip();
        // create a file
        zip.file(data, 'nameoffile.fits');
        var content = null;
        if (JSZip.support.uint8array){
            content = zip.generate({type:"uint8array"});
        } else {
            content = zip.generate({type:"string"});
        };
        $('#download').click(function(){
            var blob = zip.generate({type:"blob"});
            saveAs(blob, "downloadable.zip");
        });

    })
    .fail(function(data) {
        console.log("Failed");
        })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("In Always");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues:

- it's `zip.file('nameoffile.fits', data)`, not `zip.file(data, 'nameoffile.fits')`
- `$.get` only handles text content but [FITS files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FITS) look like binary files

`$.get` tries to decode the content from its encoding (usually UTF-8). With a binary file, the decoding step corrupts the content. You can check this step by converting the content to a blob and using `saveAs` to download it.

To fix that, see [this page](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/read_zip.html#in-the-browser): either use JSZipUtils, an `XMLHttpRequest` with `responseType = 'arraybuffer'`, or any ajax framework that let you download binary content.

Comment: Ah ha! Thanks David, that's really helpful. I'll switch round the name of file and data attributes. I do saveAs blob, $('#download').click(function(){ var blob = zip.generate({type:"blob"}); saveAs(blob, "downloadable.zip"); });, would that not do the trick?

Comment: Switching the name of the file and the data attribute seems to have done the trick, thanks!